# Trouble enabling remote connections to SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, remote-connection

I'm trying to enable remote connections but i'm having some trouble.  Here's my setup

- SQL Express is installed on Win2k8 R2.
- Windows firewall turned off
- SQL Browser service started and running
- SQL TCP/IP protocol enabled
- SQL Server configured to allow Windows & Sql authentication
- SQL Server configured to allow remote connections

With all those settings i still fail to establish a remote connection.

On the local machine i tried

```
telnet localhost 1433
Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed
```

This is a fresh installation.  What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

NVM - figured out the problem.  By default SQL server is not running on the standard port 1433.

Had to configure the TCP protocol for IPAll to port 1433.